# Eigenvalue of $W+W^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ can we say anything about the eigenvalues of $M=W+W^T$?

---

Note $\lambda_i(W) = \lambda_i(W^T)$ because $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$.

Note $M$ is symmetric because $M^T=(W+W^T)^T=W^T+W=W+W^T=M$ so $\lambda_i(M)\in \mathbb{R}$.

By eigendecomposition of $M$ we see that $M=W+W^T=U\Sigma U^T$. By singular value decomposition we see that $M=W+W^T=\hat{U}\hat{\Sigma}\hat{V}^T + \hat{V}\hat{\Sigma}\hat{U}^T$. Does this tell us anything?

If we further assume triangular $W$ then $\lambda_i(W)=W_{ii}$.

Comment: If $W$ is unspecified, you can't say anything particular...

Answer (score 1):

Because $M$ is symmetric (and thus [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Equivalent_definitions)) it holds that $\sigma_i(M)=|\lambda_i(M)|$.

The [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) $||M||=\sigma_{max}$ satisfies triangle inequality so $||M||=||W+W^T||\le ||W||+||W^T||=2\cdot \sigma_{max}(W)$.

But $||M||=\sigma_{max}(M)=|\lambda_{max}(M)|$ so we conclude $|\lambda_{max}(M)|\le 2 \sigma_{max}(W)$.